# What does "sump'n'll" mean?

Tags: american-english, slang

This sentence is cited from "Keep Going: 10 Ways to Stay Creative in Good Times and Bad"

"Every day is a new deal. Keep workin' and maybe sump'n'll turn up"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In very informal speech, this is a way of saying *something will.*

The combination of the sounds 'm' and 'th' is not easy to say quickly, and careless speakers sometimes insert a different consonant into such words as well as leaving some consonants out.